# Usage of settings.setCacheMode in webview Android

Tags: android, android-webview

What is the use of setCacheMode for webview settings?
Is it to load from cache only if there is no internet?

I guess I am looking for (this does not exist only LOAD_CASHE_ELSE_NETWORK is available).
`settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.Load_Network_ELSE_CASHE]);`

I always want to internet version first and only if there is no internet, then display cached version.

@VenomVendor thanks for reply I red your possible duplicated post and that is not same as this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading Cache when Offline in Android Webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787800/loading-cache-when-offline-in-android-webview)